# Raspberry Streaming using VLC picamera python

Tags: raspbian, python, vlc

I am trying to stream Raspberry Pi camera video using VLC. The code is as follows:

```
import subprocess
import picamera
camera = picamera.PiCamera()
camera.resolution = (640,480)
cmdline = ['cvlc','-vvv','stream:///dev/stdin','--sout','#rtp{sdp=rtsp://:8554/}',':demux=h264' ]
myvlc = subprocess.Popen(cmdline, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
camera.start_recording(myvlc.stdin, format = 'h264')
camera.wait_recroding(60)
camera.stop_recording()
myvlc.stdin.close()
myvlc.wait()
```

However, the code does not produce the desired output. Please guide me what's wrong with this code snippet.

Answer (score 1):

This is my first answer I have used this on my raspberry pi and there is almost no noticeable latency when less than 2 meters away from router, here is the code I got it from this https://randomnerdtutorials.com/video-streaming-with-raspberry-pi-camera/ I would make my own script but I have been focusing mostly on setting it up. If I am doing anything wrong in this answer please tell me and I will try and correct anything I have done wrong. This is my first answe on stack exchange. This could be an alternative to vlc which when I have tried has really high latency

```
# Web streaming example
# Source code from the official PiCamera package
# http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/latest/recipes2.html#web-streaming

import io
import picamera
import logging
import socketserver
from threading import Condition
from http import server

PAGE="""\
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</title>
    </head>
    <body>
    <center><h1>Raspberry Pi - Surveillance Camera</h1></center>
    <center><img src="stream.mjpg" width="640" height="480"></center>
    </body>
    </html>
"""

class StreamingOutput(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.frame = None
        self.buffer = io.BytesIO()
        self.condition = Condition()

    def write(self, buf):
        if buf.startswith(b'\xff\xd8'):
            # New frame, copy the existing buffer's content and notify all
            # clients it's available
            self.buffer.truncate()
            with self.condition:
                self.frame = self.buffer.getvalue()
                self.condition.notify_all()
            self.buffer.seek(0)
        return self.buffer.write(buf)

class StreamingHandler(server.BaseHTTPRequestHandler):
    def do_GET(self):
        if self.path == '/':
            self.send_response(301)
            self.send_header('Location', '/index.html')
            self.end_headers()
        elif self.path == '/index.html':
            content = PAGE.encode('utf-8')
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'text/html')
            self.send_header('Content-Length', len(content))
            self.end_headers()
            self.wfile.write(content)
        elif self.path == '/stream.mjpg':
            self.send_response(200)
            self.send_header('Age', 0)
            self.send_header('Cache-Control', 'no-cache, private')
            self.send_header('Pragma', 'no-cache')
            self.send_header('Content-Type', 'multipart/x-mixed-replace; boundary=FRAME')
            self.end_headers()
            try:
                while True:
                    with output.condition:
                        output.condition.wait()
                        frame = output.frame
                    self.wfile.write(b'--FRAME\r\n')
                    self.send_header('Content-Type', 'image/jpeg')
                    self.send_header('Content-Length', len(frame))
                    self.end_headers()
                    self.wfile.write(frame)
                    self.wfile.write(b'\r\n')
            except Exception as e:
                logging.warning(
                    'Removed streaming client %s: %s',
                    self.client_address, str(e))
        else:
            self.send_error(404)
            self.end_headers()

class StreamingServer(socketserver.ThreadingMixIn, server.HTTPServer):
    allow_reuse_address = True
    daemon_threads = True

with picamera.PiCamera(resolution='640x480', framerate=24) as camera:
    output = StreamingOutput()
    #Uncomment the next line to change your Pi's Camera rotation (in degrees)
    #camera.rotation = 90
    camera.start_recording(output, format='mjpeg')
    try:
        address = ('', 8000)
        server = StreamingServer(address, StreamingHandler)
        server.serve_forever()
    finally:
        camera.stop_recording()
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a debugger?

Are you using an IDE?

Check out Spyder from [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads)

If you're a a beginner maybe [Thonny](http://thonny.org/)

But, try breaking your code up into functions, so you more easily diagnose where the problem is. Try adding:

`stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
 stderr=subprocess.PIPE`

to you Popen() arguments, and read their outputs with

`print('pass through:', repr(stdout_value.decode('utf-8')))
 print('stderr      :', repr(stderr_value.decode('utf-8')))`

you might also want to try passing `shell=True` to [Popen](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html).

Answer (score 0):

I think this is my first solution to stack overflow instead of a question :).

What worked for me was to type your command as a string instead of a list, then use shlex.split() on that string for the Popen command.  If anyone can explain why shlex works where techraf's code doesn't, please do as I got here through mostly blind trial and error.

```
import subprocess
import picamera
import json
import shlex

vlcCommand="cvlc -vvv  stream:///dev/stdin --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=ts,dst:8080}' :demux=h264"
conf = json.load(open('conf.json'))

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
   camera.resolution = tuple(conf["resolution"])
   camera.framerate = conf["fps"]
   camera.vflip = True
   camera.hflip = True
   cvlc = subprocess.Popen(shlex.split(vlcCommand), stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
   camera.start_recording(cvlc.stdin, format=conf["codec"])
   camera.wait_recording(30)
   camera.stop_recording()

#Connect to network stream on VLC with http://ip:8080 on client
```